# Does the Meissner effect only effect magnetic fields?

Tags: superconductivity

I find this effect very interesting and was wondering what tests have been performed to check its effects on other fields?

Also a side question related to this effect, can it trap a magnetic field. For instance, If I have a hollow sphere of a superconducting material and I put it in a mag field before it is at its critical SC temperature. So now the mag field is penetrating the object, then I bring it to its critical temp, will the object hold the field that was penetrating it even after I move it away from the magnet?

Comment: NO, but interestingly that was a conceptual mistake done by people in the early years of superconductivity. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6911 section 2.

Comment: No to both questions?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the first question. I was saying *no*, a superconductor can not trap/freeze a magnetic field inside the bulk. Which other fields to you have in head ? I just know electric and gravitational fields. For both there is no repulsion as for Meißner effect repulsing the magnetic field, as far as I know. I do not know for subatomic fields. There must be kind of a Meißner effect associated to the Higgs mechanism, but I'm too remote from this topic, try adding the tags "Higgs mechanism" + gauge-theory, of something like thing, you might attract attention from high-energy physicists.

Comment: Well, in fact the question should be changed as well, so perhaps it's better to ask in an other question, something like : "Is there a Meißner-like effect associated to the Higgs mechanism ?" But it's not really a clear question, since Higgs phenomenon might well appear in vacuum...